# How to represent in Java a context-free grammar?

Tags: java, parsing, context-free-grammar, language-specifications

I have a simple grammar:

```
R --> R and R | R or R | atom
```

The only terminal we have is *atom*.
This is a recursive grammar because each R can be composed by nested R.
The problems I am facing are:

1. How to deal with recursion?
2. How to build a java class R that can be resolved by one of the 3 rules?

How would you represent this grammar by Java classes?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How to write a parser?

Comment: I already have a parser for this grammar. My goal is to write API for this grammar, so I need to represent each rule with OOP.

Comment: The API is `parse()`, or possibly a set of parse tree nodes. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Would be closers: It is *perfectly* clear what OP is asking: how he could/should he store a grammar in a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to normalize all rules as single choices, and then represent them as an array of arrays.

First we assign a unique code to each "atom" (token) in the grammar.

Then, rules should all be normalized as

```
LHS -->  RHS1 RHS2 ... RHSn
```

e.g, rules of the from:  a --> b | c should be normalized as two rules, a --> b and a --> c .  If you have other fancy notational EBNF devices such as kleene start or plus, you normalize them also.

Now you have K rules; you can define an array with K slots, each slot holds one rule.   A rule slot holds a pair: a LHS, and an array of size n for that rule.  (Easier:  a rule slot holds an array of size n+1, with the leftmost element index 0 holding LHS, index 1 holding RHS1, etc.).

Now you have the grammar represented in Java.

[Recursion is a semantic property of the grammar, not its representation.]

An alternative:  if you build a classic parser for BNF (after all, (E)BNF has a grammar, too) you can parse your BNF using the parser, and build a tree for that.  That's obviously also a representation.  It isn't a convenient as the array of arrays to process.